# How do I get the String scanner to wait?

Tags: java

I have been trying to get this thing to work but it doesn't. I want to replace the `int Scanner` to a `String Scanner`, but when I do that, it doesn't wait for the user to put in his answer.

```
System.out.println("Ditt val: "+ prov.GetCategoryName(nVal-1));
cat = prov.GetCategory(nVal-1);
int nCorrectAnswers = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < cat.nNumQuestions; i++){
    System.out.print(cat.taskArray[i].sQuestion +": ");
    int nMyAnswer = scan.nextInt();

    if(nMyAnswer == 1){
        nCorrectAnswers++;
    }
}
```

Let's say i have 3 questions and if i have int it waits for the user to put in a answer to each question but if i have String it just print out the 3 questions directly.
How do i use the 
`String nMyAnswer = scan.nextLine();` so it waits for the user to answer the question.

Comment: Are you using both `nextInt()` and `nextString()` in your code?

Comment: No, i want to change the "int nMyAnswer = scan.nextInt();" to       String nMyAnswer = scan.nextLine();

Comment: Have you use your `Scanner` for any input previously? How do you enter your input?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK? There is a bug where it doesn't halt when using the Scanner class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the API for the method nextLine():

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Try the next() method.

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

So your code would be:

```
System.out.println("Ditt val: "+ prov.GetCategoryName(nVal-1));
cat = prov.GetCategory(nVal-1);
int nCorrectAnswers = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < cat.nNumQuestions; i++){
    System.out.print(cat.taskArray[i].sQuestion +": ");
    String nMyAnswer = scan.next();

    if(nMyAnswer == 1){
        nCorrectAnswers++;
    }
}
```

Basically nextLine() is used to scan a line from a file **i.e.** it scans the string until the equaivalent of \n is found.

Comment: nextLine() should still halt and wait for input.

Comment: @Scuba Steve You're wrong; I edited my answer with an explanation.

Comment: nextLine() should get all the input up to the carriage return and advance the scanner to point at the next line.. if the system doesn't halt to get any input, then what would the point be in skipping it?

Comment: mainly, the OP hasn't misunderstood how nextLine() works, but their system isn't halting for some reason. I've encountered the same non-halting issue with OpenJDK more than a few times.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, **nextLine()** is used for parsing files. It scans a line then it advances the scanner to the next line. The API clearly states that and also states that the input that was skipped is returned. The next method however returns the next complete token, meaning the next thing that is input. I find it funny how an accepted correct answer is down-voted twice. Try it yourself, you'll find I'm right.

Comment: You usually finish IO on the console by pressing the keyboard carriage return. This feeds a new line into the stream so `nextLine()` would not be a problem. OP's problem is somewhere else. (If it works, it works for a different reason, maybe they aren't ending their inputs with carriage returns).